# Assigning an object with only keys to a require statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

This is a simple assigning statement on first step in Graphql getting started, Which I don't understand exactly

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');
```

I tried running

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');
console.log(buildSchema+"variable ends");return;
```

and

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');
console.log(graphql+"variable ends");return;
```

The first one prints a small function and the second one prints a big one. I also tried

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');
var obj = require('graphql');
console.log(obj+"variable ends");return;
```

I searched for whether does this obj consists of a function in the same name as the object properties(graphql,buildSchema).

I don't get it. So what does it mean exactly?

Comment: This is destructuring in es6. So the module graphql exports a lot of function and whenever you are requiring it you are getting an object comprises with the functions. Now when you are destructuring then you are just assignign the two functions not all of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just destructuring, which works the same way as when destructuring standard objects. Breaking it down:

`require('graphql');` returns an object with various properties, such as

```
{
  graphql: function(a, b) { ...
  buildSchema: function(schemaInfo, anotherArgument) { ...
  someOtherProperty: etc
}
```

Destructuring is a shorthand version of extracting specific properties from an object and declaring them as variables in the same statement. So:

`var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');`

is equivalent to:

```
var graphqlImport = require('graphql');
var graphql = graphqlImport.graphql;
var buildSchema = graphqlImport.buildSchema;
```

Comment: I might have missed these functions when I console log the full object.